# Default latest install of OS and NTP how to setp updates of leap-seconds.list

Tags: ntp

I have just installed a default image  and added the NTP package and added my local NTP servers to it

When NTP starts it gives the warning
".....leap-seconds.list.... will expire in less than 18 days"

This is correct as the leap-seconds.list is one version old being based on IERS Bullitin C62 which expires on 20 June 2022 and [C63](https://datacenter.iers.org/data/16/bulletinc-063.txt) has been released with expiry 28 December 2022 https://www.ietf.org/timezones/data/leap-seconds.list

I found the command "update-leap"   but it will not run as per below

```
root@raspberrypi:~# update-leap
Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::SSLeay module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.32.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.32.1 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl5/5.32 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl-base /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.32 /usr/share/perl/5.32 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /usr/bin/update-leap line 30.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/update-leap line 30.
```

I searched for SSLEAY and it seemed I might be following the wrong trail
So my question is how do I get the leap-seconds files to be updated and do it automatically from now on?

If I need to find a package with SSLEAy in it then how ?

cat /etc/os-release is as follows

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are seeing is related to the use of perl for the utility, this tool requires a few.  See the help page fr a bit more detail.  v1.004 reports the following:

### External Dependencies

The following perl modules are required:
HTTP::Tiny      - version >= 0.056
IO::Socket::SSL - version >= 1.56
NET::SSLeay     - version >= 1.49

Version: 1.004

The fix dependencies approach here is to add the perl modules it's looking for.  Namely "Net::SSLeay", and a few more as you keep digging to close down the dependencies.

first, jump into CPAN, and configure it with all the defaults if you haven't used it before (follow the prompts ):

sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell

Then, from that session, install the missing modules one after the other :

install Net::SSLeay
install IO::Socket::SSL

run it, wait for it to do it's thing, and then 'quit'.

You likely already have HTTP::Tiny installed, so this dependency was already filled for me.  If not, jump back into the CPAN console and install it just like the others

The command will now work!

Comment: The first thing it said was fetching with HTTP:Tiny   so yes its installed  for me as well it looks like your answer is correct - but I'll wait till it finished before marking it as such

Comment: one of the dependencies I had was the development version of SSL - so I had to go out of CPAN and do apt-get install libssl-dev  - the message is fairly clear that the dependency is not inside perl once I read it properly  - the sudo update-leap now runs - but says "No leapfile directive in /etc/ntp.conf; leapfile location not known" - which is false - but a different problem

Comment: sudo update-leap -u https://hpiers.obspm.fr/iers/bul/bulc/ntp/leap-seconds.list -L /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list
Does work and correct says no need to update ....

Answer (score 0):

So what I wanted was some way to be sure of no errors ie check the hashvalue and so forth - however the obvious answer is probably the easiest

```
wget https://hpiers.obspm.fr/iers/bul/bulc/ntp/leap-seconds.list 
sudo cp leap-seconds.list /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list
rm leap-seconds.list
```

seems to work fine
If I do the following on windows in PowerShell

```
wget https://hpiers.obspm.fr/iers/bul/bulc/ntp/leap-seconds.list -OutFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP\etc\leap-seconds.list"
```

with the appropriate line in the Meinburgh NTP client

```
leapfile "C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP\etc\leap-seconds.list"
```

I find a nice message about the hash value is correct so I'm hoping the Raspberry PI NTPD also checks correctly